# how to remove a datagridview row that has your textbox text value with a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview

so i have this datagridview2 that i'm using it for searching.
and when i search and find the row that i want i click on that row, and all the values go to textboxes, and there is a button that deletes the record on click using the id on textbox 1,
in another datagridview1 i have a method that refreshes the whole datagridview records when i delete that item by its id.
so back to datagridview2, i want when i delete that row, the row gets deleted also from datagridview, without using and refreshing my datagridview with my refilldatagridview() method that i created,
when i use `dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(row);`
it works without loop, as well as the removeAt index
the problem is in the loop it never enters the if and i don't know why

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Match deleted");
        dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(row);                                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're pointing out.

Using LINQ (try column name instead of column index, it's getting error if I use column index)

```
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(w => w.Cells["Value1"].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text).Select(s => s.Index).FirstOrDefault());
dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(w => w.Cells["Value1"].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text).Select(s => s.Index).FirstOrDefault());
```

Searching:
[image]

Deleting:
[image]

Just place the 2 line of code above inside of your loop.

I hope it helps!

Comment: sorry for bothering you, my code was working i just had a method that empty textboxes after deleting from datagridview1 so i never had a way to delete it from the second datagridview, i apriciate the efforts, and your code is working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there have Several way that u can try

#1 simple iteration

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView2[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text))
        dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(dataGridView2[i]);
}
```

#2    If u want to use dataTable to search

```
var query = dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>(columnName) == textBox1.Text);
foreach(var row in query.ToList())
{
       row.Delete();
}
```

Comment: sorry for bothering you, my code was working i just had a method that empty textboxes after deleting from datagridview1 so i never had a way to delete it from the second datagridview, i apriciate the efforts, and your first simple iteration is working, the second one gives an error  > Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row. thank you !